# git pull not showing in reflog -- want to reset it

Tags: git

I did a `git commit` into my local branch and then did `git pull`.  I was one commit behind the remote and that merged all the remote changes that now show in `git status` like I modified them, which is not the case.  So I want to undo the `git pull`.  I was hoping to be able to do it using `git reset HEAD@{x}` where X was the ID from the reflog before I did the pull.  But the pull is not showing in the reflog and I need to undo all the mess it did locally.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `HEAD@{commit id}`, just use `commit id`:

```
git reset commit_id
```

Also, if `git pull` moved the branch pointer, you'll see that in the reflog, though it will appear as `merge origin/master`, not a "pull".

Comment: i thought it didn't make any difference

Comment: Which, the use of `git reset commit_id` vs `git reset head@{commit_id}`? the second version isn't valid, it won't point at a commit, so it won't *do* anything. If you want to reference a commit, use its ID.